# How do you delete S3 object from the bucket in Nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, next.js, vercel

It is my first time using AWS S3. I am trying to store images (jpg/png etc.) on S3 and have the URL stored on a database. The application essentially logs the user's session and S3's URL when they submit a picture (profile picture), and when they want to update the profile picture, the original S3 stored picture will be deleted and replaced with a new one.

Currently I am using https://next-s3-upload.codingvalue.com/setup next-s3-upload, which successfully uploads images onto S3 but not deleting. The entire tech stack is NextJS, Prisma and Planetscale, to be hosted on Vercel.

Any tips on how to operating CRUD for S3 would be appreciated, as I am stuck on reading up AWS-SDK but no joy on React/NextJS.

Answer (score 2):

Read the ***AWS SDK for JavaScript Developer Guide***. This will teach you how to perform AWS operations using the AWS SDK for JavaScript, including many Amazon S3 operations.

[What's the AWS SDK for JavaScript?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html)

This SDK can be used with React too.

[Getting started in React Native](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/getting-started-react-native.html)

For Amazon S3 operations, see:

[Amazon S3 examples using SDK for JavaScript V3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/javascript_s3_code_examples.html)

To delete an object, see this topic that shows you the code example:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/javascript_s3_code_examples.html#w4aac23b9c25c13

You can also find Amazon S3 code examples in Github here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javascriptv3/example_code/s3/src

Comment: Thank you @smac2020, the github repo in particular was super useful.